# In JS how to expand default range with new range except on the first change?

Tags: javascript

I have a default 2 element array [0, 10], the expected behavior is that the first time a new array is presented, such as [2, 11], it will update into this new array [2, 11] since we no longer need the default, but for every subsequent new array presented, it will expand to min of the 0th element and max of the 1st element. Such as when passing [1, 9], the range will now be [1, 11]. And on passing [0, 12] next, it will now be [0, 12].

How can I translate this into code?

Comment: Why do you need [0, 10] at all? Why not just skip it? Where do these new arrays come from? Are you by any chance keeping them inside another array so reduce would be an option?  Also what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

In the following `f()` takes two arrays and produces a new one with the minimum of index 0 and maximum of index 1. We can just nest this function manually or if we have an array of arrays where this function would have to be applied in the given order we can just use `reduce` in combination with our own function. Since I am unsure why you would need to keep track of the original array I simply sliced it off.

```js
const f = (ar1, ar2) => [Math.min(ar1[0],ar2[0]),Math.max(ar1[1],ar2[1])]
console.log(f(f([2,11],[1,9]),[0,12]))

var arr = [[0,10],[2,11],[1,9],[0,12]];
let res = arr.slice(1).reduce(f);

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a class for the wanted updateing by respecting the first update values.

```js
class MinMax {

    constructor (reference) {
        this.first = true;
        this.values = reference.slice(0, 2);
    }

    update (array) {
        if (this.first) {
            this.values = array.slice(0, 2);
            this.first = false;
        } else {
            this.values[0] = Math.min(this.values[0], array[0]);
            this.values[1] = Math.max(this.values[1], array[1]);
        }
        return this.values;
    }
}

var minMax = new MinMax([0, 10]);

console.log(...minMax.values); // [0, 10]

minMax.update([2, 11])
console.log(...minMax.values); // [2, 11]

minMax.update([1, 9])
console.log(...minMax.values); // [1, 11]

minMax.update([0, 12])
console.log(...minMax.values); // [0, 12]
```